# Can you transfer a Minecraft World from iPod to Xbox One?

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition, minecraft-legacy-console

My daughter build a great world on her iPod. Now she got the Xbox One for Christmas , but she misses her own world. Is it possible to transfer from iPod to Xbox maybe with USB cable?

Comment: I doubt it's possible.  If it is, it probably won't be as simple as plugging her iPod into the Xbox One.

Comment: The save files use completely different formats. You'd need 3rd party software which may not exist to convert the map.

Answer (score 2):

No, the Minecraft worlds on iOS and Xbox are saved in completely different formats. As Studoku said, it would require (possibly non-existent) 3rd party software to convert the map, which I highly doubt is possible.

Comment: The worlds are infinite in PE, and not in Xbox.

Answer (score 0):

(REQUIRES A XBOX360) Very possible you would have to make a copy of the world on the iPod just in case then transfer it to  a pic/Mac via iCloud or lighting cable then copy another world onto the Xbox 360 then going into minecraft turn on the Xbox one and click transfer world from Xbox 360 to Xbox 1 and voila you have a iPod pe world on. Xbox one , you may want to watch some videos on downloading maps to Xbox one thoughts

Comment: This explains how to physically copy the file over, but the current top answer says the world files from the mobile version isn't compatible with the xbox version, and would require the use of third party programs to convert. Are you saying that converting the file isn't necessary?

Answer (score -1):

I know that this is a bit late but it is possible to convert PE maps to PC and then PC to xbox. but you'll need to download 2 or 3 third party programs.

Comment: Can you please explain what tools you need to download and how you use them to transfer the world? Otherwise this isn't much of an answer.

Answer (score -1):

Theres a thing called a seed when you go to deatils about the world.. write it down then go onto the world on Xbox One and click create world and click add seed and put in the one you wrote down and then click create then it will transfer them

Comment: That wouldn't have all of the things that she'd built.

Answer (score -5):

Yes it is possible you just have to copy the seed.

Comment: This is wrong. 1) the seed/map generation system between the devices are different 2) they want to keep the contents of the map.